# What is the difference between a pressure switch, high-pressure control, and low-pressure control in a landing gear hydraulic system?

Tags: aircraft-systems, landing-gear, hydraulic-system

This is an Arrow II landing gear diagram.

In the diagram, the high and low pressure controls look like check valves.  The pressure switch is unclear.

What are these three items, and what purpose does each one serve?

[image]

Comment: Does the manual offer no explanation?

Comment: @JWalters the plane's information manual does not, but JohnK linked this in another related post.  http://www.mikeg.net/library/files/pa28-service.pdf : I am reading through it now.  Perhaps it has what I'm looking for.

Comment: The pressure switch looks to activate in the retracted position as a cut out when the flow becomes impossible, probably at fully retracted position. This would mean that the pressure needs to be maintained in the retracted position, which suggests in case of leak or in case of cooling at high temperature the pump will start again. I am not sure of my answer, this is a just a speculative thinking!